# Live Queries subscription updates in Parse-server

Tags: websocket, parse-server, livequery

Is it possible to get subscription alerts for live queries on a single client instead of everyone. I am using the following code to get update alerts for the object 'obj' on class 'class-name'. But the alert message comes on every client( i.e every instance of running app).

```
let query_add = new Parse.Query("class-name");
let subscription = query_add.subscribe();

subscription.on('update', (obj) => {
   alert('object updated');
});
```

How can I modify this to notify only the single client.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, this seems like a problem unrelated to parse.  Generically stated, how can I run client-specific code of the form `if (I_AM_THE_SPECIAL_CLIENT) { // do something } `.  Web clients don't really have a way to ask this.  Having a particular user identity is a decent approximation, the only one I can think of.

Comment: Oh maybe! I just figured out that one has to give session token as argument in subscribe call. It works after that! Thanks!